# How to extend member (Property) in fabric.util class fabric version 2?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have to use `fabric.util.createAccessors()` in new version. So I have to extend this member function.

```
/**
 * Creates accessors (getXXX, setXXX) for a "class", based on "stateProperties" array
 * @static
 * @memberOf fabric.util
 * @param {Object} klass "Class" to create accessors for
 */
createAccessors: function(klass) {
  var proto = klass.prototype, i, propName,
      capitalizedPropName, setterName, getterName;

  for (i = proto.stateProperties.length; i--; ) {

    propName = proto.stateProperties[i];
    capitalizedPropName = propName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + propName.slice(1);
    setterName = 'set' + capitalizedPropName;
    getterName = 'get' + capitalizedPropName;

    // using `new Function` for better introspection
    if (!proto[getterName]) {
      proto[getterName] = (function(property) {
        return new Function('return this.get("' + property + '")');
      })(propName);
    }
    if (!proto[setterName]) {
      proto[setterName] = (function(property) {
        return new Function('value', 'return this.set("' + property + '", value)');
      })(propName);
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [build](http://fabricjs.com/build/), tick `Named accessors` , then download the custom build version.

or else you can do

```
fabric.util.createAccessors = function(klass){
 //.....
}
```

Comment: fabric.util.createAccessors = function(klass){
//..............
}
2nd solution is extend proparty in fabric.utill but is not work well when we call  fabric.util.createAccessors(fabric.Text);

Comment: @BansariSavasani its better build a custom version from above link.

Comment: @BansariSavasani, yes, because there are other options to set values, [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51099075/3551786)

Comment: how can set all stateProperties as par this example: obj.set('angle', angle);
in build version i am using this fabric.util.createAccessors(fabric.text); 
but i have not to used build version. So Any option there if yes then please give me example ?

Comment: @BansariSavasani, what do you mean by `stateProperties`? you want to extend that? or you want to set some value? `fabric.util.createAccessors` creates `setAngle`/`setLeft` like methods, which you can set in [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51099075/3551786). here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/1vv8gr82/16/)

Comment: Thank you so much for Helping :-). 
I have to extend stateProperties and after i have to set All.
This will work fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/durga598/1vv8gr82/16/ without build.

Comment: @BansariSavasani,what you want to add in stateProperties ?

Comment: Please check, I am working on curveText in fabric.js
  var stateProperties = fabric.Text.prototype.stateProperties.concat();
  stateProperties.push(
    'radius',
    'spacing',
    'reverse',
    'effect',
    'range',
    'largeFont',
    'smallFont',
  );

Comment: @BansariSavasani, just do like `var stateProperties = fabric.Text.prototype.stateProperties.concat( 'radius', 'spacing', 'reverse', 'effect', 'range', 'largeFont', 'smallFont');`